# Writing to file?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

What is the difference between `echo hello > a.txt` and `echo hello >> a.txt`. It is doing the same thing, why should we use `>>` instead of `>`?
And what does `<` do?

Comment: Read `man bash` and sesrch for "`Redirecting Input`" and "`Redirecting Output`"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Comment: do each of the comands twice and see the result

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` and  `>>` are two different things. If you are writing anything to a file for the first time you use `>` and when you want to add more text to the same file without overwriting the already entered text you should use `>>`, otherwise using `>`  will overwrite anything that was written there earlier.

I will show you with an example.

**Scenario 1: Text gets appended**

- Write text to file

  ```
  echo " what are you" > text1
  ```

  Content of `text1`:

  ```
  what are you
  ```
- Write more text using `>>`:

  ```
  echo "what are you doing man" >> text1
  ```

  Content of `text1`:

  ```
  what are you 
  what are you doing man
  ```

**Scenario 2: Text is overwritten**

- Write text to file

  ```
  echo "what are you" > text2
  ```

  Content of `text2`:

  ```
  what are you
  ```
- Write more text, but using `>`

  ```
  echo "what are you doing man" > text2
  ```

  content of `text2`:

  ```
  what are you doing man
  ```

The `<` on the other hand is an input redirection operator it is used to input a file to any command. For example

```
cat < file1
```

can be used to read the contents of a file called `file1`. It's the same as

```
cat file1
```

Just try them yourself ...

Comment: This answer needs formatting: read the manual on markdown, or use the formatting buttons.

Comment: SHOUTING NEVER HELPS. please do not shout.

Comment: And welcome to the site.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that commands and filenames are case sensitive, so `CAT FILE1` would have just produced an error message ...

Comment: What is difference between `<` and '|' then?